# Python Tkinter trigger keyevent when umlaut key pressed

Tags: python, unicode, tkinter

I encounter a problem when trying to bind an umlaut-key (äöü) to a Tkinter window in Python 3.

The error message Tkinter prints out is basically:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    self.tk.bind("Ä", self.take_white_ippon)
_tkinter.TclError: bad ASCII character 0x84
```

You can try this MCVE:

```
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
def doSomething(e=None):
    print("doSomething()")
# The next line is basically ignored
tk.bind("ä", doSomething)
# This line will throw the error message
tk.bind("<ä>", doSomething)
tk.mainloop()
```

You can try <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0228</kbd> to enter an `ä` (using the number pad).

I have not found any other SO/Google pages about this topic. I have only found some questions about general problems with Tkinter and non-ascii characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a program that can help you:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(text="you pushed:").pack()
var = tk.StringVar()
tk.Entry(textvariable=var).pack()
root.bind('<Key>', lambda e: var.set(repr(e.keysym)))
root.mainloop()
```

If you run that and type ä, you will see 'adiaeresis', which is what you need to bind:

```
tk.bind('<adiaeresis>', doSomething)
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. But you need to add `<` and `>` around `adiaeresis` to make it work: `<adiaeresis>`.

Comment: I don't think that's the right format for binding. It should be `<Key-adiaeresis>`.